# how to design network for connectivity between private and corporate LANs?

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, routing

there is a bunch of servers connected to shared storage in a private LAN (10.x.x.x).
this privateLAN is managed by a windows server (DHCP, DNS and directory services)

these hosts need to be from outside of the datacenter Eg. Remote desktop.

can the NIC2 on each of the hosts be connected to the other public LAN (compromising speed or security?

what are improtant considerations:

1. additional hardware? like switches?
2. routing&DNS software?

currently available hardware : Dell Powerconnect 6224 switch .... planning this for storage network.
software: windows 2003 server for DHCP, DNS, A/D ? would it be more flexible to use Linux distributions like IPCOP, Untangle etc?

all that I am looking for is good isolation between private and other networks, avoid DHCP, DNS, AD clashes.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? What are your business requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've got quality switches, and sensible NICs in your servers (Broadcom or Intel), then you might be able to do this with VLANs.  Those are two pretty big assumptions though.
And it should be less fragile than doing it with static routes.

In Theory.

Edit: 
Oooh. [Nice switch](http://www.dell.com/us/en/enterprise/networking/pwcnt_6224/pd.aspx?refid=pwcnt_6224&cs=555&s=biz) <3 .  That's definitely enough to support VLAN tagging.  Right.  So here's the theory.

Create a VLAN for your private stuff, and a VLAN for your public stuff.  You could probably use native VLAN 1 for the public, and put the private stuff on VLAN 2, or nearly any other number.

I'd probably buy a dedicated router too, to do the inter-VLAN routing.  Probably a Cisco 28xx or 29xx.  I'm not entirely convinced that the switch you've got can do interVLAN stuff with a low-enough overhead. 
It's all a little complex, without more detail, but there should be plenty of information on the internets about how to set up separate VLANs.  You could probably do it port-based, where the physical port gets a different VLAN (meaning that the servers are tied to those switch ports, IMO, not a bad thing), and this works even if the devices don't support VLANs on their NICs.

I'm sure someone else can add more detail, or you can Google about, and see what you can find.

Comment: Dell powerconnect managed 6224 for storage n/w. all servers have Intel, Broadcom NICs- any specific features required on NIC?

Comment: VLAN support...

Comment: thank you Tom. I will dig into the details... Merry Christmas & happy holidays to you too!

Comment: @Jon I don't appreciate you bowdlerizing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You would be able to perform the above using a router and NAT. If you require more information let me know.
We would need to know what router you have and what services on the network you need to access.

Comment: currently have a Dell managed switch 6224- dedicated for storage. only have few unmanaged switches at my disposal. software options for router, NAT? BTW my corporate LAN provides these services anyway, i think tweaking has to be done on the private LAN?

Answer (score 1):

What i think your suggesting is multihoming. This can get messy & will mean you have to setup static routes on each host.  Not for the faint hearted.

Comment: thanks for the response, what ways can this be achieved without multi-homing? why is static routing hard? are there any softwares that do that?

Comment: does your 10.x.x.x have a default gateway? one way around it is only have 1 nic on the box with a default gateway, then theres no need for adding in static routes on the box.  the software is part of the OS

Comment: does not have one currently, but can setup one PC as gateway. Since the switch at my disposal is managed what does it need to establish connectivity between the two LANs?